# 12.04 live usb unable to boot Clevo m98nu

Tags: boot, boot-failure, live-usb, unetbootin, yumi

I placed 12.04 on usb with yumi. grub loads fine, and upon choosing either 'try it' or 'install it', code runs up the screen. display of text disappears as normal, but then it hangs up and the caps lock light and scroll lock light both start blinking.
 when I use unetbootin, the same happens with exception to the blinking lock lights.

I have narrow experience with linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the md5sum for the .iso file you downloaded.  If it's not correct then the image file is corrupted and you will need to get a good copy.  You can get the iso file and the md5sum file from a CD mirror, eg http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs/12.04.1/

A torrent is also a good way to get the .iso if you are having trouble getting a good download.

Comment: UPDATE: Incedentally, I've gone through many iterations with multiple copys of varying sources.

I used wubi to install successfully, and it won't boot the installed OS either.

Comment: @Cameron you can edit your post and update.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try `Startup Disk Creator`. It's the standard Ubuntu utility for this sort of thing and should be installed on your system by default.